# (Django-Celery Error) ImportError: No module named myproject

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I am using Django-Celery for the first time. When I try to run the following command :

```
celery -A MyProject worker -l info
```

I get this error message:

```
ImportError: No module named MyProject
```

MyProject/MyProject/**init**.py :

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from .celery import app as celery_app


__all__ = ['celery_app']
```

MyProject/MyProject/celery.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
import sys
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'MyProject.settings')

app = Celery('MyProject')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'MyProject.settings')
sys.path.insert(0,os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'../MyProject')))
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

MyProject/MyProject/settings.py; I have included the line below :

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://localhost'
```

My Django project structure looks like this:

- Myproject

  - Myproject

    - **init**.py
    - celery.py
    - settings.py
    - urls.py
    - wsgi.py
  - Myapp

    - migrations/
    - templates/
    - **init**.py
    - admin.py
    - apps.py
    - forms.py
    - models.py
    - tasks.py
    - tests.py
    - urls.py
    - views.py
  - db.sqlite3
  - manage.py

Comment: if you're using virtualenv, keep it active, and put yourself, in the root directory of your project. and run the command again

Comment: I'm not using virtualenv but just did put myself on the root directory and boy it worked !!!
Can't believe I spent the last 4 hours on this !

Comment: awesome! keep working...